# How can I change routes in React in response to window message event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, react-router

I have a React App which is intended to be embedded into another non-react application.  It resides within an iframe on the main applications page.  The react app uses react-router (5.0.0) and react-router-dom (5.1.0) In the react app, when someone clicks a nav link, i fire off a:

```
window.parent.postMessage(window.location.pathname,"*");
```

So that i can make the parent websites url path match that of the iframe.   I have also tied into the onpopstate event of the parent window so that i can capture the back button of the browser when it is clicked and then fire off a:

```
iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(new_url, '*');
```

The idea here is that in the React app i will listen for this message and then manually route to the correct location to keep both the parent and the iframe in sync when the back button is clicked.

I have verified that when i use the back button, i do in fact get the message in the iframe, however i am confused on the best way to trigger this re-route.  For now, i put the event listener into the root element like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import Wizard from '../Wizards';

const Root = (props) => {
  var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
  var eventer = window[eventMethod];
  var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

  // Listen to message from child window
  eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log('props');

    console.log(props);
    //props.store.dispatch(push('/broadcast_wizard/step1'));
    //Router.push('/broadcast_wizard/step1');
    //this.context.history.push('/broadcast_wizard/step1');
    console.log('why?');

  },false);

  return (
    <Provider store={props.store}>
      <Router>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700"/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/broadcast_wizard/:step" component={Wizard} />
          <Route path="/:filter?">
            Root page
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default Root;
```

In the above examples i have included (commented out) all the things that i have tried so far that have failed.  Please help, new to React but many years of JavaScript experience.

Comment: If you just want to navigate to another path you can try this:  
`window.location.href = '/broadcast_wizard/step1'`

Comment: yes i could do this, i guess i should have clarified that i want the internal page to re-route without the annoying full page refresh that would happen if i did a window.location.href =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to render the React app in an iframe? Have you explored mounting it on another root element? This might make things easier

Something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('react-root') as HTMLElement
)
```

Comment: Not sure if it would work for all of the use cases i had in mind.  My initial build of this is intended to go within a page on our main website, however in the future we envision this being embedded in third party websites as well.  I don't know enough about react yet to know if your suggested method would work for that use case.

Comment: You could mount it on that element in an iframe later if you want

Comment: I fought long and hard to make this work in an iframe but i seem to have failed.  There are some inherent problems with the window.history object that i just can't overcome.  One of the other main reasons I wanted it in an iframe was so that the parent pages CSS would not affect it, but i can manually override those if needed.